# Querying letter mu in Sparql

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib

I am using python library RDFLIB to query on semantic dicom owl file. I need to query for a label containing letter mu. I am not able to figure out how to query for labels containing this letter. The code is given below -

```
q = """SELECT ?ur WHERE{?ur rdfs:label "Exposure in uAs".}"""
qres = g.query(q)
for row in qres:
    print(row)
```

I am not getting any results for the above query.

The semantic dicom owl files contain the following triples - 
Image of what I am trying to search [contents of sedi file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ5M8.png) (<10 reputation, can't post images)

SEDI file - [Semantic Dicom OWL file](http://data.bioontology.org/ontologies/SEDI/submissions/6/download?apikey=8b5b7825-538d-40e0-9e9e-5ab9274a9aeb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the greek letter *μ* (U+03BC), but the *micro sign* (U+00B5).

The following code works for me in Python 3.6:

```python
q = """SELECT ?ur WHERE{?ur rdfs:label "Exposure in µAs".}"""
qres = g.query(q)
for row in qres:
    print(row)
```

The following code works for me both in Python 2.7 and Python 3.6:

```python
q = """SELECT ?ur WHERE{?ur rdfs:label "Exposure in \u00b5As".}"""
qres = g.query(q)
for row in qres:
    print(row)
```

Comment: How to type &\mu in the string q. Using the unicode \xB5 for &\mu throws error.

Comment: Unfortunately the query did not work for me. I am working on Windows 7 64-bit platform with python 2.7 installed using anaconda.